# Exception encountered during context initialization

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

[image]

```
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext     refresh

WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emp' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [com.avi.spring.firstspring.employee]: Bean property 'id' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emp' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [com.avi.spring.firstspring.employee]: Bean property 'id' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1711)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.avi.spring.firstspring.test.main(test.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [com.avi.spring.firstspring.employee]: Bean property 'id' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:426)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:266)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Could you please share your Employee class code? Probably you've missed to write setter method for id property in Employee class.